# Making OpenCart 2.2 Installation 100% HTTPS

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have just installed OpenCart 2.2 on my website today, running on an Apache server, running PHP Version 7.0.8.

The website already has an SSL certificate installed, and I can visit the shopping catalogue via:

```
https://example.com/printshop/index.php
```

I want the whole setup to run on SSL, so I have edited the relevant config files as follows:

**https://example.com/printshop/config.php**

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://example.com/printshop/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/printshop/');
```

**https://example.com/printshop/admin/config.php**

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://example.com/printshop/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://example.com/printshop/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/printshop/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://example.com/printshop/');
```

The problem I am having is that the pages are not 100% secure because the form action is pointing to a non secure URL - e.g.

```
<form action="http://example.com/printshop/index.php?route=common/currency/currency" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-currency">
```

The same applies to the login form (i.e. it's action is pointing to http not https):

https://example.com/printshop/admin/index.php?route=common/login

And from any page, the print shop logo (held in `<div id="logo">`) returns the user to a non HTTPS page.

Apart from changing the URLs in the config files as I have already done, is there no global setting anywhere which allows me to sets the URL of the installation?

---

**Updated to include solution**

Thanks to advice from @Vipul Jethva, I got a solution for this.

Edit /system/library/url.php

Change code from:

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = false) {
    if ($this->ssl && $secure) {
        $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
    } else {
        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
    }
    ...
}
```

To:

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = true) {
    if ($this->ssl && $secure) {
        $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
    } else {
        $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
    }
    ...
}
```

Plus make sure to update config.php in the root of your installation, and admin/config.php to also point to https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s ,

There is following code on controller file.

```
$this->url->link('common/home');
```

You need to pass last two parameter like,

```
$this->url->link('common/home','',true);
```

Last two parameter is using for SSL.

If you need to check code for it. Then got System -> Library -> Url.php file.

> Default **$secure** parameter is **false**.

Either you will make default $secure parameter = true or make last parameter on the controller file.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Vipul Jethva. I have edited the url.php file as suggested, which seems to clear up some of the issues, but still if I go to the admin login page, even going to https://oracle101.co.uk/printshop/admin/index.php?route=common/login, the form action is still pointing to http not https. Do I need to edit something here: **admin/controller/common/login.php** All I can see is `$data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/login', '', true);` which is already set to true isn't it? Thanks

Comment: You will make https on system -> liabrary-> url. Only If condition have https. so you will also make https on else condition.